# Cannot get inner content of div_images because the contents are not literal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error below. Please see in my code below & suggest me what I was done wrong.

***HTML :***

```
    string ProductImages = string.Empty;
string str_query = string.Empty;
DataTable dt_Common = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bind_images();
    }
}
```

***Code :***

```
 private void bind_images()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        str_query = "select top(5) image from tbl_product_images where productinfo_id='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "'";
        dt_Common = new CommonClass().bind_department(str_query);
        if (dt_Common.Rows.Count> 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt_Common.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                div_images.InnerHtml += "<a  class=\"activeborder\" data-image=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"] + " data-zoom-image=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"] + "><img src=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"] + " /></a>";     // Getting error in this line.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

**I tried it from last days but doesn't get the solution. Any suggestion really appreciate.**

Comment: Have you tried `.InnerText` property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this:

```
StringBuilder _StrB = new StringBuilder();

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        str_query = "select top(5) image from tbl_product_images where productinfo_id='" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "'";
        dt_Common = new CommonClass().bind_department(str_query);
        if (dt_Common.Rows.Count> 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt_Common.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                image.Src = dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"].ToString().Replace("~", "..");
                _StrB.Append("<a id=" + i + " class=\"activeborder\" data-image=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"].ToString() + " data-zoom-image=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"].ToString() + "><img src=" + dt_Common.Rows[i]["image"].ToString() + " /></a>");
            }
            
        }
        string AllHTMLImages = _StrB.ToString().Replace("~", "..");
        div_images.InnerHtml = AllHTMLImages;
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use innerHtml after the control was rendered. use `RenderControl` instead, as explained here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1168614.aspx

Comment: Can u write a text please because still it is showing error !

Comment: StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        div_images.RenderControl(w);
        string s = string.Empty;

Comment: Dim sw As IO.StringWriter = New IO.StringWriter()  :
div_images.RenderControl(New HtmlTextWriter(sw))  :
Dim s As String = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString()

Answer (score 0):

string value = ((Literal)(cell.Controls[0])).Text